# Vue 2 - How to set default type of array in props

Tags: javascript, types, vuejs2, vue.js

I have my Vue component, which is taking an array of objects as a prop.
I often use prop validation, especially for 'default' value feature.

in this case I have:

```
props: {
    items: Array
}
```

but I'd like it to have like in Typescript or React:

```
props: {
    items: Array.of(
        {key: {type: String, default: 'myText'}}
        )
}
```

etc.

Is it possible to achieve? Otherwise I need to use computed data as map just to set the defaults

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I created example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjb2ke5s/1/), that might can help you, and yes... you can return the default value as a array:

**ES6**

```
props: {
    items: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => []
    }
}
```

Comment: Vue prop default does not kick in for `null`, only `undefined`, so is not equiv to `if (!items)...`. Try in fiddle `<animals :animal="null"></animals>`.

Answer (score 33):

ES6 variety For an **Array**

```
props: {
  arr: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => []
  }
}
```

...And for an **Object**

```
props: {
  obj: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({
      param: value,
      param2: value,
    })
  }
}
```

**A couple related resources:**

1. https://github.com/vue-styleguidist/vue-styleguidist
2. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1032

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```html
props: {
  data: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
    default: ()=> []
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from the other answers?

Comment: you can set this props is mendatory or not using "required" property. if your props is not required then no need to set default property or if your props is required then default is needed

Comment: Okay, please consider editing your answer to include this. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Apparently it's best practice to always set defaults - the [eslint-plugin-vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/) has a [vue/require-default-prop](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/require-default-prop.html#vue-require-default-prop) rule which is strongly-recommended and states that all props - even not required ones - should have a default value.