# Vue: Best way to set a default for a prop that is an Array?

Tags: vue.js

I have component that has a prop `orders` that is an array that returns the orders of a customer.  When the component mounts, it emits a call to the parent to make an API call, then refreshes the prop.  It is very possible that orders is an empty array if a user has no orders, in which I have a message that says "No orders exist for this user".
The issue is that since I'm it as a prop of type array, the default value of the prop is `[]` (empty array) so even on the initial component load, the template sees the orders are `[]` and shows "No orders exist message" but then a second later when the props are refreshed, it shows the orders.
I am trying to set the initial value of `orders` to null so that I can handle the specific case of when the orders are not set from api yet.  I tried adding `default: null` so that I have my prop like this:

```
props {
   orders: {type: Array, default: null}
}
```

but that is still not working correctly because the `orders` prop is still an empty array on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrays, you need to return default value from function like this:

```
props {
  orders: { type: Array, default: function() { return null; }
}
```

You can also use arrow function

```
props {
  orders: { type: Array, default: () => null }
}
```

Comment: I liked the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005856/470749