# Missing return Type on Function in Vue 3 with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

My code looks like this,

```
    <template>
      <div>        
        <ul v-if="list.length !== 0">
          {{
            list
          }}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        
        list: {
          type: Array,
          default: () => {
            return []
          },
        },
        
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Am I missing something, because I am getting error on this line:

[image: Error screenshot]

I also tried solution from this page, but nothing works.

[Vue 2 - How to set default type of array in props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553596/vue-2-how-to-set-default-type-of-array-in-props)

Comment: As error said, you are missing function return type`default: () : Array => {...}`. You defined prop type, but not function return type.

Comment: Can you please post a solution for that?
Because the code u wrote above didn't work.

Comment: `Array` also needs an element type or simply `any`, e.g. `Array<number>`. Unfortunately I don't know what's this type should be by following your code.

Comment: List of String should be returned

Comment: `@typescript/eslint` normally only runs on TypeScript. Why is it shown for your JavaScript? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, but a warning that the anonymous function should indicate a return type. Your IDE shows the name of the check, and searching for it leads to a page with [good examples](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md).

The warning should be fixed like this:

```
list: {
  type: Array,
  default: ():Array => {
    return []
  },
},
```

Comment: It shows new error now.

Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.

Answer (score 0):

As error said, you are missing function return type. You defined prop type, but not function return type.

It should look like this (in place of any you should also specify type):

```
export default {
  props: {
    list: {
      type: Array,
      default: () : Array<any> => {
        return []
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: It shows error ==> Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files. Unexpected any. Specify a different type.

Comment: As error said, change `any` to `string` (as you said in previous comment). If you still cannot figure it out, then create minimal working example here (in your post) or e.g. on codesandbox, because you have a mess in your project and it's hard to guess what you have there. I don't know whats your projects settings are.

Answer (score 0):

As a general hint I would suggest that if you are using Vue 3 + Typescript you should take advantage of the defineComponent function to wrap your component options object as documented here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components. If you are using the recommended linting settings (and your IDE is working correctly) the problem should be solved